# Is there an equivalent of CDI's @Default qualifier in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In CDI, I could do this:

```
// Qualifier annotation
@Qualifier
@inteface Specific{}

interface A {}

class DefaultImpl implements A {}

@Specific
class SpecificImpl implements A {}
```

And then in a class:

```
@Inject
A default;

@Inject
@Specific
A specific;
```

It works because of the `@Default` qualifier automatically assigned to injection points not specifying any qualifiers.

But I'm working with Spring and was unable to perform that.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
```

The problem is that the "default" injections (without qualifiers) are already used in lot of code I can't change, and I need to provide another possible implementation of `A` for my users.

I'm aware that I could inject my new implementation by bean name, but I would like to avoid it.

Is there anything in Spring that could help me achieve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Someone pointed at me that @Primary does exactly this.  I tried and it works perfectly :

```
@Primary
class DefaultImpl implements A {}
```

In my case DefaultImpl was in xml :

```
<bean id="defaultImpl" class="DefaultImpl" primary="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could have added this as a comment, but I wanted to add some code with formatting to explain my point and that is the reason why I am adding an explicit answer.

Adding on to what you have said, you can actually leverage your Specific meta-annotation within Spring also, along the following lines:

Redefine `@Specific` with Spring specific `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` annotation this way:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Qualifier
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Primary
public @interface Specific {
}
```

I have tagged Specific annotation with `@Primary` annotation also now.

With this in place your old code should just work:

```
@Specific
class DefaultImpl implements A {}
```

Comment: But in my case, DefaultImpl is not `@Specific`.  It's SpecificImpl that must be `@Specific`.  DefaultImpl must be `Primary`